# FSharp.Data HTTP Utility RequestString response Body is prepended with the word "Text"

Tags: f#, f#-data

I'm making a simple web call (GET) to an api that returns some json. Trouble is, I can't parse it with Newtonsoft (or otherwise) because the HTTP Utility RequestString response.Body is prepended with the word "Text".

```
Text
  "[{"name":"10 Years","desc":"","descData":null,"closed":false  ...
```

What can I do to avoid this and get my json string as an actual json string?

Comment: That doesn't look like it's "prepended", it looks like it's wrapped in a constructor. How did you determine that it's "prepended" exactly?

Comment: Sorry. That was just a lack of understanding and the only way I knew how to describe it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at the [FSharp.Data Http Utils ResponseBody docs](https://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/reference/fsharp-data-httpresponsebody.html) you will notice it returns a [Discriminated Union](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/discriminated-unions) with 2 options.

So you will want to handle it with something like this:

```
let myHttphandler resp =
    match resp with
    | Text txt -> txt |> customTextHandler
    | Binary bytes -> bytes |> customBytesHandler
```

Of course, if you know you will always get text, use `_` in your [DU](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/discriminated-unions).

Your `customTextHandler` function will probably deserialize your json.

Comment: Unbelievable I missed that. I was just pushing Body.ToString() out of habbit and false assumptions. I will look at it today and report back. Thank your pointing out my lack of attention to detail on this one.